# Subapps in Web.py always return 405

Tags: python, web.py

Well, this is in my code for the app.py

```
urls = (
    '/', 'Index',
    '/Test', 'module.test_module.test_app'
    )
```

my test_module.py

```
import web
urls = (
  "/(.*)", "Test"
)

class Test:
    def GET(self):
        return "HELLO"

test_app = web.application(urls, locals())
```

entering via Browser `0.0.0.0:8080/Test`
I get this in my console:

```
yanniks-mbp:page user$ python app.py
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
127.0.0.1:55914 - - [09/Jul/2014 22:47:43] "HTTP/1.1 GET /Test" - 405 Method Not Allowed
```

So my folder structure looks like this:

```
app.py
module (folder)
  |
  - __init__.py
  - test_module.py
  - other_files.py
```

I think I mess something up really bad with the imports or direct declaration in the URLs but I don't know what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You dont't need to run `web.application` in your `test_module`, you can directly refer to the class `Test` in your `app.js`.

app.py

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'Index',
    '/Test', 'module.test_module.Test'
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

module/__init__.py

```
import test_module
```

module/test_module.py

```
class Test:
    def GET(self):
        return "HELLO"
```